# Django retornando ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estou criando um projeto para envio de emails, porém estou fazendo alguns testes e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

> The view send_mail.core.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Logo abaixo seguem minhas linhas de código:

```
#views
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.template.context import RequestContext
from .forms import SendMail


def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SendMail(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            print(form)
            return render_to_response('index.html', 
                context_instance=RequestContext(request, {"form": form},))
    else:
        print("ops!!")


#forms
from django import forms


class SendMail(forms.ModelForm):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=80)


#template
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>some title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="." method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form.as_p}}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Não preciso salvar os dados em um banco de dados, portanto não estou utilizando um model, preciso apenas que, o que eu escrever dentro do campo `textarea` seja printado. Futuramente quero enviar emails com o mesmo, o intuito é criar um email sender, aonde vai conter um campo com o email do cliente e um `textarea` com o assunto desejado.

Alguém sabe me dizer o porque do erro acima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce tratou o `form` quando o método é `POST` e se for `GET`? só um "ops!"?
Tente deixar sua view de acordo com o codigo abaixo, fazendo as adptações necessárias.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SendMail(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            print (cd)
            form = SendMail()   # Limpando o form
        else:
            print ('Valores inválidos')
            print (form.errors)

    else:
        form = SendMail() # Inicicializando o form

    return render(request, 'caminho/sua_template.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Perfeito meu querido, funcionou perfeitamente, fico grato por sua ajuda. outro problema é que o forms.ModelForm pede por padrão um model, portanto alterei o mesmo para forms.Form.